# View "What's New" in landscape in the Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-7, tablet

When I'm on my Nexus 7 (2013) in landscape mode, the Play Store shows me the permissions list, but nothing about what's changed in the application being updated. In portrait mode I get the full details. Is there some way to quickly view application details in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I would figure this out just after asking the question:

You can view the application details in landscape mode by first selecting the application in the left-side panel, then clicking the larger application icon or title in the right-side pane.